# Web API route not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is my web API config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ReaderTags",
           routeTemplate: "Reader/{readerID}/Tags"
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

I want that when I call my URL `/Reader/abc/Tags` it should call my ReaderController's Tags action and pass `abc` as the string parameter.

But somehow it is using the `DefaultAPI`'s route and trying to find `abc` as an action in `ReaderController`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route mapping is missing defaults that would let the route table know what controller and action to invoke for routes matching the template

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ReaderTags",
    routeTemplate: "Reader/{readerID}/Tags",
    defaults: new { controller = "Reader", action = "Tags" }
);
```

The route template also assumes that the string parameter on the action shares the same name: i.e: `readerID`.

```
public IHttpActionResult Tags(string readerID) {
    //...
}
```

And since `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` is also configured, then the same can be achieved via attribute routing instead of convention-based routing like this

```
//GET Reader/abc/Tags
[HttpGet]
[Route("Reader/{readerID}/Tags")]
public IHttpActionResult Tags(string readerID) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant stuff